# Comparing a string to a .txt file

Tags: python, string, text, browser-history

I have posted a question earlier about reading a string element in browser history, but now I realized I need to compare the elements of that string file to an external .txt file. Here is what I've done using.

```
from browser_history.browsers import Chrome

f = Chrome()

outputs = f.fetch_history()

string1 = str(outputs.histories)

file1 = open("grey.txt", "r")

readfile = file1.read()

if string1 in readfile:
    print("TRUE")
else:
    print("NAH FAM")

file1.close()
```

I have the word google in the .txt file. I know google.com is in the string outputted by the browser-history module.

```
if 'google' in str(outputs.histories):
    print(True)
```

That line of code prints true, however using an external text file does not seem to work.

Comment: Is it possible you have a trailing newline at the end of your file?  If you add ".strip()" after file1.read() does that change anything?

Comment: @inteoryx. I guess the further issue is that the text file will have a couple terms inside of it, and if only one of the terms in the string matches one of the couple terms in the text file, it will spit out a true value. Right now, it will spit out false unless there is only one value (that value being true).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @inteoryx in the comment.

I think the problem is with the whitespaces.
When you load a external file as string , the whole line is selected.

Moreover, I think there is an error in this too , `

```
if string1 in readfile :
```

it should be done like this :

```
if readfile in string1:
```

You should do something like this :

```
from browser_history.browsers import Chrome

f = Chrome()

outputs = f.fetch_history()

string1 = str(outputs.histories)

file1 = open("grey.txt", "r")

readfile = file1.read()

readfile = str(readfile)
readfile = readfile.strip()

if readfile in string1:
    print("TRUE")
else:
    print("NAH FAM")

file1.close()
```

EDIT :
for multiple checks it can be done like this :

```
from browser_history.browsers import Chrome

f = Chrome()

outputs = f.fetch_history()

string1 = str(outputs.histories)
count = 0

file1 = open("grey.txt", "r")

readfile = file1.read()

readfile = str(readfile)
readfile = readfile.strip()

read = readfile.split(',')

for i in read :
    
    if i in string1:
        count = count+1


if count == len(read) :
    print("True" , len(read))
else :
    print("NAH FAM")
file1.close()
```

`

Comment: That does work for single elements, but I might as well just use a string. When putting multiple terms inside of the text file, it will always print no, even if one of those terms is present in the string. The other not being present causes a no. I am looking to put together a few terms inside of the text file and if just one of them is present it spits out a true. Hopefully that makes sense! I don't believe putting any inside of the code helps, because any has to have an iterable I believe.

Comment: What is the separator used in the text file to separate the word ?

Comment: A comma, for example I would go Youtube, Google, Twitter. Even if I had gone to google and twitter but not youtube, it would come up as false.